# How Can I Create Columns to Cargorize My results based on certain criteria SQL

Tags: sql

How can I categorize results if they fit one of the following criteria?

For instance, if I have a column that displays the number of days between two other columns then have another column that shows the category below if would fall under. So for a line item that has 3 days listed between two dates it will show A: 0-5 on that line item.

```
A: 0-5
B: 6-10
C: 11-15
D: 16-19
E: 20-30
```

Comment: question is not very clear. Please put it in a tabular format, both input and output to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when col between 0 and 5 then 'A'
             when col between 6 and 10 then 'B'
             when col between 11 and 15 then 'C'
             when col between 16-19 then 'D'
             when col between 20 and 30 then 'E'
         end) as category
from . . .;
```